# Docker time is not the same as on my windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows, docker

I have my container running in docker but when i look at some lines that i printed with the corresponding time. I see that it's every time 2 hours behind.

---

What I've done:

- I did a software update
- I removed every container and created them again
- I added this piece of code as a volume in my docker-compose.yml file

  - `/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro`
  - `/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro`

But none of this work

---

What causes this problem?
How can i fix this?

This is a screen of my problem
[image: This is a screen of my problem]

Comment: who says the time in container is guaranteed to be same as host?

Comment: I figured that docker uses the UTC. Thats why my host is 2 hours in front of docker. But will this cause errors or not?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic in SO.  Besides Google "docker container timezone" will find an explanation and solution.  For example https://mohitgoyal.co/2021/03/02/change-timezone-in-docker-and-oci-compliant-containers/